# In javascript, how to get value stored in an array stored in an object property, whose parent object is stored in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In javascript, how can you get a value stored in an array stored in an object property, whose parent object is stored in an array?

Here is my object. I can see what's inside it, but I don't know how to access those values inside the array. I tried a lot of ways from different questions, but I failed to find the way... there must be something I'm not doing right. Here is the code:

```
    this.Object3dName = New3DobjectName;
    this.Object3dId = NumberOf3Dobjects;
    this.Object3dFaces = new Array();
    var face1 = new Array(); //Faces properties in index order: texture1(background in css3),texture2(background-image in css3), type3(possible types are triangle, rectangle and circle), faceHeight4, faceWidth5, X-position6, Y-position7, Z-position8, X-axis9, Y-axis10, Z-axis11, SelectedOrNot12 and reflect13
    face1[0] = "default";       // texture1
    face1[1] = "default";       // texture2
    face1[2] = "default";       // texture3
    face1[3] = "rectangle";     //type  
    face1[4] = "100px";         //height  
    face1[5] = "100px";         //width
    face1[6] = 0;               // X-postion
    face1[7] = 0;               // Y-postion
    face1[8] = 0;               // Z-postion
    face1[9] = 0;               // X-axis
    face1[10] = 0;              // Y-axis
    face1[11] = 0;              // Z-axis 
    face1[12] = "NotSelected";  // SelectedOrNot12
    this.Object3dFaces.unshift(face1);

    all3dobjectArray.push(this);

    console.log("You clicked on the object who's id is: " + myobjectindexpostion);
    console.log("You clicked on the object : " + all3dobjectArray[myobjectindexpostion]);
    n = all3dobjectArray[myobjectindexpostion].Object3dFaces;
    m = n[6];
    console.log( "n: " + n + "deg  m: " + m );
```

Comment: If your `n =` line works, and that array has at least seven (note: seven) entries in it, then the `m =` line should work. Show how you're creating the array.

Comment: var myvarname = new Array();

Comment: @ Slain: That array is empty. How are you creating *and populating* the array? Fundamentally, the code above is fine: http://jsbin.com/narinobo/1

Comment: I've added how I populated and create those array, it's weird that I see the array but can't acess the value directly. Maybe If I store it in a variable ?

Comment: You didn't push "face1" anywhere. Did you mean to push it onto this.Object3dFaces?

Comment: yes I pushed it in .Object3dFaces which was made like this :           this.Object3dFaces = new Array();

Comment: @Slain: Your quoted code doesn't push `face1` anywhere. You push `this` (whatever that is), but not `face1`.

Comment: ok you want me to post the whole thing ?

Comment: @Slain: Fundamentally, what you need to do is use the debugger built into your browser to step through the code and see what you're really creating. If you were really creating what you described, that code would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine:

```
this.Object3dFaces = new Array();
var face1 = new Array();
face1[0] = "default";       // texture1
face1[1] = "default";       // texture2
face1[2] = "default";       // texture3
face1[3] = "rectangle";     //type  
face1[4] = "100px";         //height  
face1[5] = "100px";         //width
face1[6] = 0;               // X-postion
face1[7] = 0;               // Y-postion
face1[8] = 0;               // Z-postion
face1[9] = 0;               // X-axis
this.Object3dFaces.push(face1);
all3dobjectArray = new Array();
all3dobjectArray.push(this);

var shouldBeZero = all3dobjectArray[0].Object3dFaces[0][6];
console.log('shouldBeZero', shouldBeZero);
```

Is it what you intended?

If you're pushing `face1` onto `Object3dFaces`, and it's the only element, then you're going to get `undefined` at index 6. You want to access `face1` at index 0 and then access the sixth element of `face1` after that. See above.

Comment: I cant access n[6] it's undefined for some reason, but n return the right array !?